# MYSQL Trigger doesn't allow update same table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table commits and I would like to update all records that has a similar hash in the field message. 
However it does not allow me to update the same table that's used the trigger.
I tried putting a transaction in the procedure but then I get an error that an implicit or explicit commit is not allowed in a function or trigger. (even though it's in the procedure.)

I'm not very familiar with mysql procedures, I'm hoping you know a way around this.

This is the procedure that will update all the other records

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_commits_by_message_id` (IN messageId VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

   DECLARE approvedAt DATETIME;
   DECLARE approvedByUserId INT(11);

   SELECT approved_at, approved_by_user_id 
   INTO approvedAt, approvedByUserId 
   FROM commits 
   WHERE message LIKE CONCAT('%', messageId, '%')
   AND approved_at IS NOT NULL
   LIMIT 1; 

   UPDATE commits
   SET 
   approved_by_user_id = approvedByUserId,
   approved_at = approvedAt
   WHERE message LIKE CONCAT('%', messageId, '%')
   AND approved_at IS NULL;

END//
```

This is the trigger and it calls the procedure above with the message id

```
CREATE TRIGGER `commit_equalizer` 
BEFORE INSERT
ON commits 

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE changeId VARCHAR(250);

   SET changeId = SPLIT_STR(NEW.message, 'Change-Id: ', 1);

   CALL update_commits_by_message_id(changeId);

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: SQL Server is not mySQL - please tag appropriately.

Comment: I looks like a catch 22 since you are using the trigger and SP both on the table [commits]. Can you move the SP into the trigger itself? Why do you need the SP 'update_commits_by_message_id' separately, is it being used anywhere else?

Comment: I already tried that moving it inside, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql doesn't allow this.
See documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9

> **B.5.9: Can triggers access tables?**
>
> A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger can also affect other tables, 
> **but it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used** (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger

Comment: and nobody knows a way around this?